# Ubuntu 14.04: Screen turns blank, but system still ON

Tags: 14.04, drivers, screen, lenovo

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo X1 carbon 3rd gen(Broadwell, Intel HD 500 graphics). Since latest Intel video driver update screen started to go blank regularly. In the meantime system is running just fine and I can get into GUI by **Ctrl-Alt-F1** and then **Ctrl-Alt-F7**. Even if I continue typing all keypresses are registered, just the screen is black. 
My kernel: `Linux X1 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu`
I can also close the lid and suspend the system then it resumes normally. After a while(seconds, minutes) I get black screen again.
Tried to search, but can get similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for updates and installed them if there any?

What display manager are you using?
to find out paste the output of:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

Comment: Yes, checked and installed all updates proposed. Display manager is lightdm

Comment: Can you use Ethernet connection and boot to TTY and run                           sudo apt-get remove lightdm                                then reinstall it with.                                      sudo apt-get install lightdm                            then see if you are still experiencing this issue.

Comment: Why can't I do it using terminal? Or I can SSH via Wi-Fi and do it as well?

Comment: You can do it using SSH VIA WiFi. It's better to do it using TTY To make sure the display manager is actually removed.

Comment: I still get the blackscreen issue after removing/installing lightdm. It is really annoying and I have no idea what can be done.

Comment: I also notice that there might be connection between wifi connection and black screen - it usually happens when using wifi, and (very) rarely when using 3G or wired connection.